# ionic side menu scope variable

Tags: controller, ionic-framework

I want to add dynamic content to my side menu based on scope variables defined in services.js

currently the content of the user array doesn't load.

my app.js to define the controller.

```
.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
  $stateProvider

  .state('menu', {
    url: '/menu',
    templateUrl: 'templates/menu.html',
    controller: 'MenuCtrl'
  })
```

controllers.js

```
angular.module('starter.controllers', [])

.controller('MenuCtrl', function($scope, UserInfo ) {
  $scope.user = UserInfo;
})
```

services.js

```
angular.module('starter.services', [])

.factory('UserInfo', function() {
  var User = {
    fname : "First",
    lname : "Last",
  };

  return User;
});
```

menu.html

```
<ion-side-menus enable-menu-with-back-views="false">
  <ion-side-menu-content>
    <ion-nav-bar class="bar-stable">
      <ion-nav-back-button>
      </ion-nav-back-button>

      <ion-nav-buttons side="left">
        <button class="button button-icon button-clear ion-navicon" menu-toggle="left">
        </button>
      </ion-nav-buttons>
    </ion-nav-bar>
    <ion-nav-view name="menuContent"></ion-nav-view>
  </ion-side-menu-content>

  <ion-side-menu side="left">
    <ion-header-bar class="bar-stable">
      <h1 class="title">{{user.fname}} {{user.lname}}</h1>
    </ion-header-bar>
    <ion-content>
    </ion-content>
  </ion-side-menu>
</ion-side-menus>
```

Comment: Are you getting any error or something ? I am able to successfully see the 'first last' coming up as side menu header title with the same code you have given here. Did u inject both the `starter.controllers` and `starter.services` module to the `starter` module creation in app.'s file ?

Comment: oh that's odd.  yeah i have `angular.module('starter', ['ionic', 'starter.controllers', 'starter.services'])` in my app.js file